# "Invalid argument While reading flags on" problem on deleting files in linux system

Tags: rm, ntfs, delete

I recently received an "Invalid argument while reading flags on" problem while deleting files in a Linux system.

I cannot delete some (very big files) on a Linux filesystem. I don't know what to do!

```
id
uid=1000(elias) gid=1000(elias) ομάδες=1000(elias),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),46(plugdev),116(lpadmin),122(sambashare)

ls -ld . ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 elias elias 4096 Feb 17 17:04 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 elias elias 4096 Jul 14 18:33 ..
```

sudo rm *

```
rm: cannot remove '01st - O Basikos.avi': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove '02nd - The Pigs.avi': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove '02nd - The Pigs - short2.AVI': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove '03rd - O Glaros.avi': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove '04rth - Gio-Gio.avi': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove '07th - To Paixnidi tis Sfagis.avi': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove '08th - I Drakaina.avi': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove '09th - O Zitianos.avi': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove '10th - Troades.avi': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove '69082056_498303567665424_7547131835499675648_n.png': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove '69507971_2418284725052'$'\350\243\260''78_7036264017014292480_o.jpg': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '69515885_2418284525052598_830424852870463488_o.jpg': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove '69584492_2418284805052570_8494867853135052800_o.jpg': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove '69868065_2418284518385932_7450056396264964096_o.jpg': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '69936932_2418284865052564_2431600811281743872_o.jpg': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '69'$'\350\243\260''37965_2418284665052584_6232500998267469824_o.jpg': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '6th - Ta Frouta tou Pneumatos.avi': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove '70447879_2418284535052597_6811504792116920320_o.jpg': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove '70615044_2418284641719253_3543323980268044288_o.jpg': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove 'Ektos - O Epitheoritis.avi': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove 'Melina Tanagri.avi': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove 'Vraveia.avi': Input/output error
```

and lsattr...

```
 elias@eliasc:/media/elias/MyPassport/Events - Personal - Vids/Theatrikoi Diagonismoi 33oi-Zografou-2019a$ lsattr
lsattr: Invalid argument While reading flags on ./01st - O Basikos.avi
lsattr: Invalid argument While reading flags on ./02nd - The Pigs - short2.AVI
lsattr: Invalid argument While reading flags on ./02nd - The Pigs.avi
lsattr: Invalid argument While reading flags on ./03rd - O Glaros.avi
lsattr: Invalid argument While reading flags on ./04rth - Gio-Gio.avi
lsattr: Invalid argument While reading flags on ./07th - To Paixnidi tis Sfagis.avi
lsattr: Invalid argument While reading flags on ./08th - I Drakaina.avi
lsattr: Invalid argument While reading flags on ./09th - O Zitianos.avi
lsattr: Invalid argument While reading flags on ./10th - Troades.avi
lsattr: Invalid argument While reading flags on ./69082056_498303567665424_7547131835499675648_n.png
lsattr: Invalid argument While reading flags on ./69507971_2418284725052裰78_7036264017014292480_o.jpg
lsattr: Invalid argument While reading flags on ./69515885_2418284525052598_830424852870463488_o.jpg
lsattr: Invalid argument While reading flags on ./69584492_2418284805052570_8494867853135052800_o.jpg
lsattr: Invalid argument While reading flags on ./69裰37965_2418284665052584_6232500998267469824_o.jpg
./69868065_2418284518385932_7450056396264964096_o.jpg: No such file or directory
./69936932_2418284865052564_2431600811281743872_o.jpg: No such file or directory
lsattr: Invalid argument While reading flags on ./6th - Ta Frouta tou Pneumatos.avi
lsattr: Invalid argument While reading flags on ./70447879_2418284535052597_6811504792116920320_o.jpg
lsattr: Invalid argument While reading flags on ./70615044_2418284641719253_3543323980268044288_o.jpg
lsattr: Invalid argument While reading flags on ./Ektos - O Epitheoritis.avi
lsattr: Invalid argument While reading flags on ./Melina Tanagri.avi
./Vraveia.avi: Input/output error
```

and ls -lQ *

```
    elias@eliasc:/media/elias/MyPassport/Events - Personal - Vids/Theatrikoi Diagonismoi 33oi-Zografou-2019a$ ls -lQ *
ls: cannot access '69868065_2418284518385932_7450056396264964096_o.jpg': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '69936932_2418284865052564_2431600811281743872_o.jpg': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'Vraveia.avi': Input/output error
-rwxrwxrwx 1 elias elias 15053658390 Sep  6  2019 "01st - O Basikos.avi"
-rwxrwxrwx 1 elias elias   458762716 Sep  6  2019 "02nd - The Pigs - short2.AVI"
-rwxrwxrwx 1 elias elias 10775490376 Sep  7  2019 "02nd - The Pigs.avi"
-rwxrwxrwx 1 elias elias 12010358308 Sep  9  2019 "03rd - O Glaros.avi"
-rwxrwxrwx 1 elias elias  7789788922 Sep  9  2019 "04rth - Gio-Gio.avi"
-rwxrwxrwx 1 elias elias  7377647868 Sep 12  2019 "07th - To Paixnidi tis Sfagis.avi"
-rwxrwxrwx 1 elias elias  7289683606 Sep 16  2019 "08th - I Drakaina.avi"
-rwxrwxrwx 1 elias elias  8526826412 Oct 14  2019 "09th - O Zitianos.avi"
-rwxrwxrwx 1 elias elias  9300601002 Oct 14  2019 "10th - Troades.avi"
-rwxrwxrwx 1 elias elias     1343557 Sep  6  2019 "69082056_498303567665424_7547131835499675648_n.png"
-rwxrwxrwx 1 elias elias      143518 Sep 11  2019 "69507971_2418284725052\350\243\26078_7036264017014292480_o.jpg"
-rwxrwxrwx 1 elias elias      151257 Sep 11  2019 "69515885_2418284525052598_830424852870463488_o.jpg"
-rwxrwxrwx 1 elias elias           0 Feb 18 00:43 "69584492_2418284805052570_8494867853135052800_o.jpg"
-rwxrwxrwx 1 elias elias      159896 Sep 11  2019 "69\350\243\26037965_2418284665052584_6232500998267469824_o.jpg"
-rwxrwxrwx 1 elias elias 13958209594 Sep 11  2019 "6th - Ta Frouta tou Pneumatos.avi"
-rwxrwxrwx 1 elias elias      145183 Sep 11  2019 "70447879_2418284535052597_6811504792116920320_o.jpg"
-rwxrwxrwx 1 elias elias           0 Feb 18 00:44 "70615044_2418284641719253_3543323980268044288_o.jpg"
-rwxrwxrwx 1 elias elias 11083624324 Sep 14  2019 "Ektos - O Epitheoritis.avi"
-rwxrwxrwx 1 elias elias  7974938232 Sep 16  2019 "Melina Tanagri.avi"
```

and dmseg....

```
    [   84.158595] audit: type=1400 audit(1594676419.746:51): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_mmap" profile="snap.anbox.container-manager//null-/usr/sbin/aa-exec" name="/usr/sbin/aa-exec" pid=1582 comm="aa-exec" requested_mask="rm" denied_mask="rm" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   84.158602] audit: type=1400 audit(1594676419.746:52): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_mmap" profile="snap.anbox.container-manager//null-/usr/sbin/aa-exec" name="/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so" pid=1582 comm="aa-exec" requested_mask="rm" denied_mask="rm" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   84.159084] audit: type=1400 audit(1594676419.746:53): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="snap.anbox.container-manager//null-/usr/sbin/aa-exec" name="/etc/ld.so.cache" pid=1582 comm="aa-exec" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   84.159152] audit: type=1400 audit(1594676419.746:54): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="snap.anbox.container-manager//null-/usr/sbin/aa-exec" name="/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so" pid=1582 comm="aa-exec" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   84.159157] audit: type=1400 audit(1594676419.746:55): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_mmap" profile="snap.anbox.container-manager//null-/usr/sbin/aa-exec" name="/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so" pid=1582 comm="aa-exec" requested_mask="rm" denied_mask="rm" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   84.159326] audit: type=1400 audit(1594676419.746:56): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="snap.anbox.container-manager//null-/usr/sbin/aa-exec" name="/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so" pid=1582 comm="aa-exec" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   84.159330] audit: type=1400 audit(1594676419.746:57): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_mmap" profile="snap.anbox.container-manager//null-/usr/sbin/aa-exec" name="/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so" pid=1582 comm="aa-exec" requested_mask="rm" denied_mask="rm" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   84.195823] bridge: filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables is no longer available by default. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this.
[   84.203002] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): lxcbr0: link is not ready
[   84.243401] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max)
[   93.236203] kauditd_printk_skb: 7 callbacks suppressed
[   93.236204] audit: type=1326 audit(1594676428.826:65): auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 ses=4294967295 pid=1582 comm="anbox" exe="/snap/anbox/158/usr/bin/anbox" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=165 compat=0 ip=0x7f718849fb9a code=0x7ffc0000
[   93.284036] resource sanity check: requesting [mem 0x000c0000-0x000fffff], which spans more than PCI Bus 0000:00 [mem 0x000d0000-0x000d3fff window]
[   93.284203] caller os_map_kernel_space.part.8+0x10b/0x150 [nvidia] mapping multiple BARs
[   93.497901] audit: type=1326 audit(1594676429.086:66): auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 ses=4294967295 pid=1582 comm="anbox" exe="/snap/anbox/158/usr/bin/anbox" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=165 compat=0 ip=0x7f718849fb9a code=0x7ffc0000
[   93.500379] audit: type=1326 audit(1594676429.090:67): auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 ses=4294967295 pid=1582 comm="anbox" exe="/snap/anbox/158/usr/bin/anbox" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=165 compat=0 ip=0x7f718849fb9a code=0x7ffc0000
[   93.505450] audit: type=1326 audit(1594676429.094:68): auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 ses=4294967295 pid=1582 comm="anbox" exe="/snap/anbox/158/usr/bin/anbox" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=165 compat=0 ip=0x7f718849fb9a code=0x7ffc0000
[12326.801458] perf: interrupt took too long (2538 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 78750
[17231.226813] perf: interrupt took too long (3213 > 3172), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 62250
[23067.074788] perf: interrupt took too long (4030 > 4016), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 49500
[24415.334432] audit: type=1400 audit(1594700750.025:69): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/9436/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=21658 comm="apparmor_parser"
[24415.334440] audit: type=1400 audit(1594700750.025:70): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/9436/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=21658 comm="apparmor_parser"
[24415.630792] audit: type=1400 audit(1594700750.321:71): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.hugo.hugo" pid=21660 comm="apparmor_parser"
[24415.804123] audit: type=1400 audit(1594700750.493:72): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.hugo" pid=21662 comm="apparmor_parser"
[24415.815070] audit: type=1400 audit(1594700750.505:73): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.core" pid=21663 comm="apparmor_parser"
[24415.833547] audit: type=1400 audit(1594700750.521:74): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.core.hook.configure" pid=21664 comm="apparmor_parser"
[30198.603216] usb 3-9: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[30198.752148] usb 3-9: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6366
[30198.752150] usb 3-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[30198.752151] usb 3-9: Product: Mass Storage Device
[30198.752153] usb 3-9: Manufacturer: Generic
[30198.752154] usb 3-9: SerialNumber: 058F63666433
[30198.752667] usb-storage 3-9:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[30198.752757] scsi host8: usb-storage 3-9:1.0
[30199.887649] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Multiple Card  Reader     1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[30199.888108] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[30201.023835] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] 31387648 512-byte logical blocks: (16.1 GB/15.0 GiB)
[30201.024168] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[30201.024169] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[30201.024469] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[30201.024472] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[30201.028920]  sdc: sdc1
[30201.030266] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[30219.804093] FAT-fs (sdc1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
```

dmesg | grep EXT4 .....

```
 dmesg | grep EXT4 
   [    6.161317] EXT4-fs (sdb2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null) [   14.696792] EXT4-fs (sdb2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

As it was suggested, I did:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

added: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="fsck.mode=force fsck.repair=yes"
and then, I ran `update-grub`.

My HDD is not mounted automatically at boot. I didn't see that fsck checked it at all.

DISKS utility find data on that HDD as NTFS. How I can check its filesystem integrity without using Windows?

Comment: Use `fsck` to repair those file system errors. For more information on how to use it, refer to [this post](https://www.tecmint.com/fsck-repair-file-system-errors-in-linux/)

Comment: @Rayleigh Do not link other web sites when unneeded, please. Look on our site, there already is my question addressing this at boot time, which is what he / she needs.

Comment: @Rayleigh i faced a problem. fsck says cannot check my (gpt) drive due to bad magic block. I run gdrive and says all ok. What I can do now?

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak You are right I'll keep that in mind. Estatistics, this problem is out of scope for this question. Please post a new question detailing your problem so that the community can help you.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak i posted my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62901646/in-linux-fsck-gpt-external-hard-disk-fail you can move it at linux sub forum or create a new one?

Comment: @Estatistics Please edit your GRUB config to check your file system at boot: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="fsck.mode=force fsck.repair=yes"` and the run `update-grub` and reboot. Should not it help, add to your question that you did this and it did not help.

Comment: @Estatistics Please use [edit button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62901646/edit) on your SO question, simply copy paste wherever you need it, and delete the original. Cheers, and good night.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak I cannot find grub/default but `elias@eliasc:~$ sudo vi /etc/grub.d/
00_header         20_linux_xen      30_uefi-firmware  README
05_debian_theme   20_memtest86+     40_custom         
10_linux          30_os-prober      41_custom         
elias@eliasc:~$ sudo vi /etc/grub.d/`

Comment: `sudoedit /etc/default/grub`. I need to go now. Bye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 15Jul2020, there is no option to check filesystem integrity of a Hard disk formatted as NTFS under Linux.

What I did?

- I downloaded the free trial of Windows Enterprise as ISO
- `sudo apt-get remove virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox*`
- Install the latest Virtualbox from [here](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/)
- Download the matched version of Virtualbox extpack
- Add to disk group, me, as user, due to access deny hard disk error

  - `sudo usermod -a -G disk $USER`
  - `sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers $USER`
- Run `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`
- Run VirtualBox, and add Virtualbox extpack at File -> Preferences -> Extentions
- Restart your Computer
- Create a link to your physical Hard Disk which is NTFS (either usb or not) using `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "</path/to/file>.vmdk" -rawdisk /dev/sdX`
- Create Machine -> New -> Windows 10 (64bit) (whatever match) -> Create a Virtual Disk
- Attach the Downloaded Windows Enterprise Free trial ISO image
- At your newly created Virtual Windows Image --> preferences -> Storage -> attach the vmdk image of your ntfs hdd
- It may fail. Dont worry. To me failed too. I refer to it, because I found it. It may work for you.
- Go to Virtual Windows Image --> preferences -> USB, check USB 3, add your NTFS HDD
- Run your Virtual "Windows Enterprize Free Trial" machine.
- Click Continue, Repair your computer (at left down side), Troubleshooting, Run Command Prompt
- Go to your disk by writing eg. C:
- Check that it is your disk somehow eg. dir
- Run chkdsk /f when you are on your disk

This process fixed my NTFS filesystem that it was fault. I hope it helpt you too.

If you find any easier solution, only under Linux, please post it.