# problem deleting files in a 1TB NTFS USB drive

Tags: sudo, usb-drive, ntfs

I have a pc with dual boot (Windows 8.1 + MX Linux), I'm using FreeFileSync as my backup apps, since the last few updates I did few months back, neither FreeFileSync nor GSmartControl worked with Silicon Power drive (I tried a month back a new backup, it failed on my SP 1TB external drive), previously GSmartControl could recognize SP drive, but now it won't see it, and when tried to do backup, got errors (`G_IO_ERROR_FAILED: Trash portal failed on /media/michael/SP PHD U2/data/media/ebook/fiction/best seller/conto English1.epub [g_file_trash]`), tried to delete the file manually (either through terminal or Thunar), got `Input/output error` (even using `sudo`).
Tried to use the following commands (`sudo rm -f cont*` & `lsattr conto*`), both failed. rm did not return any message, but the file is still there, see the output below

```
$ sudo rm -f conto*
michael@mx:/media/michael/SP PHD U2/data/media/ebook/fiction/best seller
$ ls
'conto English1.epub'
```

and lsattr gave the following error

```
lsattr: Invalid argument While reading flags on conto English1.epub
```

Found a solution similar to mine on this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/598459/invalid-argument-while-reading-flags-on-problem-on-deleting-files-in-linux-sys), I've never worked with VirtualBox in Linux, better ask before doing something stupid, I'd like to make sure that this will solve my problem.
ps: my Windows in dual boot is corrupted, so I can't boot to Windows.

Comment: This could be down to 1) disk corruption 2) fs corruption 3) malfunctioning ntfs-3g driver

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, sorry forgot to mention that the drive must be OK, because even the delete command gave error, I can still open the file using Foliate, so I assume my file must be OK, it seems more likely malfunctioning of ntfs-3g driver, how do I fix it?